# How do I go into root and have it change my prompt?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-10.04, root

I am using ubuntu-10.04 and bash. I want to go into root and have it change my prompt to underlined red characters to reflect that I am in root. At the bash prompt, if I type:

```
$ sudo bash
```

then I go into root, however my prompt doesn't change. In `/root/.bashrc` I have:

```
RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
UNDERLINE="\[\033[4m\]"
DEFAULT="\[\033[0m\]"
export PS1=$RED$UNDERLINE'\u@\h:\w\$'$DEFAULT' '
```

however this file isn't being read. In order for it to be read I have to enter at the prompt:

```
# . /root/.bashrc
```

which I don't want to have to do. How do I set it up so that when I go into root, `/root/.bashrc` runs automatically?

Answer (score 2):

- First, is `sudo root` even a valid command? (`sudo -s` or `sudo -i` would be.)
- I prefer editing my *own* `.bashrc` instead of root's. You can have, for example,

  ```
  if (( $UID == 0 )); then
      PS1="$RED$UNDERLINE"
  else
      PS1="$GREEN"
  fi
  PS1="$PS1\u@\h:\w\$$DEFAULT "
  ```
- You can use `sudo -i` to make root's rcfiles be read instead of yours.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `sudo bash`. You're right, `sudo root` is meaningless. Anyway, your suggestion of an if statement on the $UID works.

Comment: @Philip: If an answer is helpful, consider [marking it as accepted](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like sudo is configured to use the original users's environment variables and not the new ones.

Either you set the `env_reset and env_keep options in /etc/sudoers` or you explicitly reset the environment variables to the ones of the target user with `-H`: 
**`sudo -H -u root`**